# errorhandler express invalid

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, custom-error-handling

i try handling error with errorhandler middleware bu it does not work, why? If i use custom handleerror all be all right. Can you help me? I am new in node.js and i have difficult beginnings heh.

```
var express = require('express'),
timeout = require('connect-timeout'),
errorhandler = require('errorhandler');
var app = express();
//app.use(errorhandler({log:errorFunction}))

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(timeout('2s'))


app.get('/slow-request',function(req,res,next){

setTimeout(function(){

    if(req.timedout){return false}
    console.log("Time is ok, i can use next()")
    },3000)

})

/*
function errorFunction(err,str,req)
{
    console.log("ERRORfromerrorHandler!!!!!");//never called? why?
}
*/

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
console.log("ERRORfromMyCustomErrorFunction!!!!!")// it is ok
});


var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: remove err from `app.use(function(err, req, res, next){..})` only req,res, next

Comment: My function is good; p asking about :/ *
errorFunction function (err, p, req)
{
     console.log ("ERROR !!!!!!!!!!"); // never called? why?
}
* /

Answer (score 0):

Your error handler is fine.

Instead of using `setTimeOut`, `throw` an error and your error handler will catch it.

Comment: It will output the `console logs` on the server side, the terminal running the express app NOT on the browser. Do you see `'Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port` on the terminal, you should. Its the same place where you will see any other console logs

Comment: I know that ;p I tested it on console promt!! ;)

Comment: Well if you throw some error, the error handler will catch it and display any console logs made there. Are you throwing any error? I don't think so. Note: Error handlers are only invoked when there are any errors.

Comment: Replace that with `throw new Error('An error. dammit')`

Comment: why i replace that? ;p;p this thorw error, but if i use middleware errorhandler is not working;p when i test it in my custom errorHandler it working perfect

Answer (score 0):

think you understand me, my errorhandler is good, i know!! and it is display "ERRORformMyCustomErrorFunction";p(it perfect:P) but.... i ask about errorhandler(express middleware) (only ) why does not display on the console "ERRORfromerrorHandler!!!!!" It does not work me only that,what is between /*..........*/